# Lua tables analogue in C++

Tags: c++, lua

I started to learn C++ after many years coding in Lua (the only one language I know). Help me please write the same code in C++

```
ticker_list="GAZP,SBER,GMKN"
period_muvinga={}
period_muvinga.GAZP=23
period_muvinga.SBER=19
period_muvinga.GMKN=20
for sec in string.gmatch(ticker_list,"%a+") do
   local period=period_muvinga[sec]
end
```

The main question is about 100% analogue of Lua tables in C++.

Comment: You can achieve something similar using `std::map` and `std::any`, but it will never be as flexible. C++ is not a scripting language, and, as you should be aware when learning any language, you shouldn't try to "code lua, but in C++". Learn C++ idioms instead of trying to mimic other language constructs. Good studies!

Comment: `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` come close, but they aren't 100% analogous - first of all, Lua type system is dynamic, while C++'s is static, so you have to specify for each map the type for the keys and for values. Besides, there's nothing like the metatable, weak tables & co. You can cover the same use cases, but you shouldn't try to replicate Lua in C++ - it's a different language with different features and patterns. You apply some patterns when working in Lua, some different ones in C++.

Comment: @Kosmonavt: "*the only one language I know*" There is a tendency among people who have only programmed in one language to assume that all other languages are just variations on what they know. This is not the case. To approach learning a new language by trying to map the new language's constructs to what you know in the old one is folly. Each language must be approached on its own terms, by learning the tools specific to that language.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is the equivalent code written in c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::map<std::string, int> period_muvinga;

  period_muvinga["GAZP"] = 23;
  period_muvinga["SBER"] = 19;
  period_muvinga["GMKN"] = 20;

  //  Iterate over all the key,value pairs in map
  //
  for (const auto & p: period_muvinga)
    {
      // Extract key from pair
      std::string ticker = p.first;

      // Extract value from pair
      int period = p.second;

      std::cout << ticker << " = " << period << std::endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

As others have said, `std::map` is not exactly the same as lua tables. So depending on what you want to do, `std::map` may or may not fit your needs